# Database transaction doesn't roll back in JModelAdmin - Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, transactions

I am developping a calendar component for Joomla 3.x. I use MySQL 5.5.32

In the backend, I have a form to save the event data in the database and upload an image.

To deal with the image I extend JModelAdmin and I override the save function.

```
public function save($data)
{ 
  [...]

  $db = $this->getDbo();

  try
  {
    $db->transactionStart();

    // Move uploaded image in correct folder
    if($image = FileUtility::preprocessJFormFile('image', '/images/aftevents/'))
    {
      $fileExtension = JFile::getExt($image);
      // register the image extension to be saved in the database
      $data['image_ext'] = $fileExtension;
    }


    if (parent::save($data))
    {

      // Rename image with event id
      if($image)
      {

        $id = $data['id'] ? $data['id'] : $this->getState($this->getName().'.id', 0);

        if(!$id)
        {
          throw new Exception('COM_AFTEVENTS_EXCEPTION_NO_ID', 1502);
        }

        $finalImage = JPATH_ROOT.'/images/aftevents/'. $id .'.'. $fileExtension;

        JFile::move($image, $finalImage);

        // Create thumbnails
        $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_aftevents');
        $params->toArray();
        $IEWidth = $params['image_event_width'];
        $IEHeight = $params['image_event_height'];
        $ICWidth = $params['calendar_image_event_width'];
        $ICHeight = $params['calendar_image_event_height'];

        $jimage = new JImage($finalImage);
        $thumbs = $jimage->createThumbs(array($IEWidth.'x'.$IEHeight, $ICWidth.'x'.$ICHeight), 5);
      }

      $db->transactionCommit();
      return true;
    }

  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
      // catch any database errors.
      $db->transactionRollback();

      $this->setError($e->getMessage());
      return false;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Now the transaction doesn't work. If an exception is caught, the insertion in the database isn't rolled back.

I believe it is because the transaction instructions and the database insertion are not called by the same JDatabaseDriver object or somewhere in the parent classes another transaction is used when the the record is saved in the database and it messes up this one.

Does anybody know how make my transaction work?

Comment: So your idea is to wrap the called parent save() in a transaction and also in a try catch? Keep in mind that you are not passing the $db to the parent and that the parent itself is not doing the update query, that is happening in the JTable class. I would say what you might do is in your table class provide a store() method that includes transaction support.

Comment: I see your point. I am going to try that and let you know. The thing is it doesn't make much sense dealing with the image in the Jtable class though.

Comment: Is your goal not to save a record if the upload doesn't work? I'd do the upload before the save() in that case.

Comment: My script takes care of the upload of the file before the insertion in the database. What I have to do after, is rename the file with the id of the event and create some thumbnails. I could take of that before an update but for an insertion I have to do it after to get the id generated by autoincrement in the database.

Comment: Alright I did what I wanted by copying the full save function of the JModelAdmin class directly in my subclass and adapting the code above. I actually have access to the right JTable object in that function. It's slightly dirty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions can only be used against transaction-aware **storage engine such as InnoDB**. All core Joomla tables use InnoDB however 3rd party extensions may not. Check this before using transactions.

Change your Table Storage Engine as InnoDb.